# Concatenate fields from one column in one table into a single, comma delimited value in another table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Any help that can be provided to a Access and VB noob would be greatly appreciated.  What I'm trying to do is concatenate the values from one table and insert it as a comma delimited value into a field in another table.  I'm trying to take all the server names that are say Linux boxes and concatenate them into a different field.

Table A looks like this

```
Machine Name | Zone   | Operating System
----------------------------------------
Server01      Zone A    Linux
Server02      Zone B    Linux
Server03      Zone A    Windows
Server04      Zone C    Windows
Server05      Zone B    Solaris
```

Table B has the field I want to insert into: Affected_Machine_Names.

Now, I've tried looking through the Concatenate/Coalesce posts, but the SQL view in Access doesn't like the Declare statements. My VB skills suck badly and I can't seem to get the code to work in VB for Applications.  Unfortunately, I can't get this database converted into our SQL farm cause I don't have a server available at the moment to host it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This can be done with a User Defined Function, but are you sure you wish to do this? What is the real world problem? Someone may be able to suggest a lateral approach more in keeping with a relational database.

Comment: Oddly enough, this is easier with ADO, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92698/combine-rows-concatenate-rows/93863#93863

Comment: @Waughsie: You can use my [DJoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62587753/combo-box-to-select-value-w-multiple-duplicates-populating-textbox-in-form-w/62589561#62589561) function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Concatenate values from related records](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) by Allen Browne for this.  Copy the function code from that web page and paste it into a new standard module.  Save the module and give the module a name different from the function name; modConcatRelated would work.

Then I think you should be able to use the function in a query even though you're not proficient with VBA.

First notice I changed the field names in TableA to replace spaces with underscores.  With that change, this query ...

```
SELECT
    sub.Operating_System, 
    ConcatRelated("Machine_Name", "TableA", 
        "Operating_System = '" & sub.Operating_System & "'") AS Machines
FROM [SELECT DISTINCT Operating_System FROM TableA]. AS sub;
```

... produces this result set:

```
Operating_System Machines
Linux            Server01, Server02
Solaris          Server05
Windows          Server03, Server04
```

If you can't rename the fields as I did, use a separate query to select the distinct operating systems.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TableA.[Operating System]
FROM TableA;
```

Save that as qryDistinctOperatingSystems, then use it in this version of the main query:

```
SELECT
    sub.[Operating System], 
    ConcatRelated("[Machine Name]", "TableA", 
        "[Operating System] = '" & sub.[Operating System] & "'") AS Machines
FROM qryDistinctOperatingSystems AS sub;
```

Comment: I got it working with this!  I actually had the field names with underscores, but when I copied the table, I copied the label IDs that I put in without the underscores, so your first code snippet worked.  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly basic VBA function that will loop through every row in a column, and concatenate it to a comma-delimited result string. i.e., for your example, it will return "Server01, Server02, Server03, Server04, Server05".  (Don't forget to replace the column and table names)

```
Function ConcatColumn(OS As String) As String
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * from TableA")

    Dim result As String

    'For every row after the first, add a comma and the field value:
    While rst.EOF = False
        If rst.Fields("Operating System") = OS Then _
            result = result & ", " & rst.Fields("MyValue")
        rst.MoveNext
    Wend

    'Clean it up a little and put out the result
    If Left(result, 2) = ", " Then result = Right(result, Len(result) - 2)
    Debug.Print result
    ConcatColumn = result
End Function
```

To use this,
1. `ConcatColumn("Windows")` will return "Server04, Server03"
2. `ConcatColumn("Linux")` will return "Server01, Server02"
3. `ConcatColumn("Solaris")` will return "Server05"
4. `ConcatColumn("")` will return "".

Comment: Right, but what if I just separated all the operating systems into 3 separate tables from my master table in another query.  It's ugly, but it just might work.  I'll try it and report back.  Thanks!

Comment: In @PowerUser's defence, the requirement was not described very clearly by the OP!

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, HansUp.  It's simple enough to fix. I've added some IF statements and put in a OS parameter. Better?