# MS Access Concatenate function -- allow no duplicates

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

looking through StackOverflow I was able to find what I was looking for from:
[Concatenating multiple rows into single line in MS Access [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217234/concatenating-multiple-rows-into-single-line-in-ms-access)

Which utilizes the function from:
[Concatenate values from related records](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html)

But what I can't figure out is how to not return duplicate values from the rows that are being concatenated. Examples...I want it to return for Customer1:

```
PartA, PartB, PartF
```

Not...

```
PartA, PartA, PartA, PartB, PartB, PartF
```

I am not honestly sure on how to make this custom function work like that. My query is...

```
SELECT DISTINCT PART_NUMBER, 
ConcatRelated("SUPPLIER_NAME","tbl_supplier_list",
              "PART_NUMBER=""" & [PART_NUMBER] & """")
FROM tbl_supplier_list;`
```

Comment: Within the arguments, number 3, it's stated  
"If the foreign key field is Text (not Number), include quote marks as delimiters, e.g.: "[ForeignKeyFieldName] = """ & [PrimaryKeyFieldName]   & """"" 
So I used this as the keys are not just numbers but include text.

Answer (score 2):

Modify the `ConcatRelated()` function [from Allen Browne](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) as follows:

```vb
Do While Not rs.EOF
    If bIsMultiValue Then
        'For multi-valued field, loop through the values
        Set rsMV = rs(0).Value
        Do While Not rsMV.EOF
            If Not IsNull(rsMV(0)) Then
              If InStr(strOut, rsMV(0)) = 0 then  ''''' ADD THIS
                strOut = strOut & rsMV(0) & strSeparator
              End If                         ''''' ADD THIS
            End If
            rsMV.MoveNext
        Loop
        Set rsMV = Nothing
    ElseIf Not IsNull(rs(0)) Then
        strOut = strOut & rs(0) & strSeparator
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

The `InStr()` function will check to see if the current value is already in the output string `strOut`.  If it is (as indicated by a return of zero), the `If()` statement will ensure the current value is not added.