# Why is this error causing a loop instead of exiting the function?

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime-error, ms-access-2016

I was casting around SE and the web yesterday looking for a way to concatenate specific fields from multiple records together as part of a query/report structure in my Access database. I found [this SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217234/concatenating-multiple-rows-into-single-line-in-ms-access) which led me to Allen Browne's ConcatRelated() function  [here](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html). After getting off on the wrong foot by naming the module the same as the function, I got it working as desired.

However, On my initial attempt to use it in a query, I made a dumb mistake and fed it parameters that equated to `"WHERE Employee = " & [Employee]` instead of the correct`'WHERE Employee = ' & [Employee] & "'"` necessary to evaluate as a string. This resulted in the expected 3464 (data type mismatch) runtime error but with Allen's modifications it showed the actual string that caused the error. No surprise, I'll just click ok and go fix the SQL. I was surprised to find that didn't work. As soon as I clicked away the msgbox it would come back again. I used `Ctrl+Break` to stop the code but clicking `End` caused it to go right back to the same error rather than actually ending the Function. The only way I could stop the loop was by clicking `Debug` which drops me into the code as expected but I couldn't get out of the code to change the original Query. Hitting reset caused the error to pop again and put me right back in the loop.

I eventually got out of it by commenting everything out of the Error Handler and telling it to `Exit Function`. I knew that most likely was only masking the problem so I added a counter and had it increment every time the error handler was called then checked the value in the Immediate window. Sure enough, it would go up by 10 or more each time I clicked somewhere in the query.

What I don't understand is what is causing the error to loop. `Err_Handler` should dump it out of the function on the first error since there's nothing telling it to attempt to `Resume` and it specifically directs it to `Exit_Handler` which resets a couple variables and then does `Exit Function`. Even directly putting `Exit Function` in `Err_Handler` still causes multiple increments to the my error counter. Further experimenting with `Debug` highlights the line `Set rs = DBEngine(0)(0).OpenRecordset(strSql, dbOpenDynaset)`. I don't know that it helps that much since it's the first line after the function constructs the value of `strSql`. Commenting it out caused the next line to be highlighted.

I know why caused the initial error (my mistake) and that's an easy fix. I'm more interested in the unintended result of the mistake and the loop it created.

tl;dr

1. What would cause this error to loop instead of exiting or breaking?
2. Why would it seem to occur a finite number of times if error handling calls an immediate exit but adding something like `msgbox` first seems to loop infinitely, or at least until I got tired of clicking.
3. Is there a way to circumvent this in the code so that it actually stops after the fist error?

I initially was using a table with 600+ records but then experimented further with a small table of only 10 records.
Small Table Query `SELECT TestEmpHistory.Employee, ConcatRelated("EmpGroup", "TestEmpHistory", "Employee = " & Employee) AS CompliedNames
FROM TestEmpHistory` to reproduce the error.
The table `TestEmpHistory` is in the following format:
ID(AutoNum)|Employee|EmpGroup| Other fields not referenced in the query

---

ID|Employee  | EmpGroup|

1 |Employee1| G&A 
2 |Employee1| Sales 
3 |Employee2| CSR 
4 |Employee2| G&A 
5 |Employee3| CSR 
6 |Employee3|Programming 
7 |Employee3| G&A 
8 |Employee4| CSR 
9 |Employee4| CSR 
10|Employee4| Programming

I'm using Access 2016

Comment: I do not think anyone is going to read all your question, could you summarize it or adding some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without reading the whole post, I'm guessing the reason you're in a loop is because it's running this code for every row returned by the query. The only way to get out of this is, when you break into the code temporarily comment it all out so that the query can complete without generating the error for every row. Once this has completed, you can go back and correct your query design before un-commenting the function code and trying again.

Comment: I had to read this a couple times before it clicked but it makes sense. This is the first time I've used a function in a query. The function isn't stuck in a loop, it's the query that's calling the function that is essentially stuck. The problem was upstream of where I was looking. The thing that threw me off in my troubleshooting was that ErrorCount was only usually returning 33-35 errors when there were 600+ lines in the query. It only did that because that's how many lines are visible on the screen! I narrowed the row height and ErrorCount increased to match.

Comment: Upvoted and marked as answered although I don't have the rep for the upvote to count at this point.