# Error 3464: data type mismatch in criteria expression using Allen Browne's Concat function

Tags: ms-access

I am looking to concatenate this table using http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html:

[Test2 Query2]

```
Cc       Product Code  
1        a  
1        b  
2        c  
3        d  
3        e  
4        f  
4        g  
4        h
```

into

[Test2 Query3]

```
Cc       Product Codes  
1        a, b  
2        c  
3        d, e  
4        f, g, h
```

My current SQL view is this:

```
SELECT [Test2 Query2].Cc, 
ConcatRelated("[Product Code]", "[Test2 Query2]", 
              "[Test2 Query2].Cc = """ & [Test2 Query2].Cc & """") AS [Product Codes] 
FROM [Test2 Query2];
```

When I run this however, it returns "Error 3464: Data type mismatch in criteria expression".

*Note: Product Code is stored as a short text and Cc is a number.

I have also tried referencing [Concatenating multiple rows into single line in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217234/concatenating-multiple-rows-into-single-line-in-ms-access) to no avail.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try  updating `"[Test2 Query2].Cc = """ & [Test2 Query2].Cc & """"`  to `"[Test2 Query2].Cc = " & Cc`

Comment: Did you mean to say "Product Code is stored as a short text"? Doubled quote (or an apostrophe) delimiters are for text fields, not number type. Use # for date field parameters.