# combo box to select value w/ multiple duplicates & populating textbox in form w/ value from each duplicate record, line by line?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm currently trying to do as said in the title, but cannot find a reliable and working vba code to use.

The database contains 2 forms and 2 tables.

1 table **needs** *1 unique* record per name with *multiple* '**description values**', while the other **has** *multiple* *duplicate* records per name with only 1 '**description value**' each.

The '**unique name**' table needs to have a single record containing all the '**description values**' from the '**duplicate name**' table's multiple records' '**description value**'.

I was under the impression that using a **DLookup** querying the '**duplicate names**' on the '**duplicate name**'s table would return all the '**description values**' that i could just set to the textbox's value i.e.

```
Me.txtDescription.Value = DLookup("[Description]", "Duplicates Table", "[Dupe Names] = '" & cboUniqueName & "'")
```

But it would only return a single record into the text box. I've also tried the following code

```
Dim dQry As String
Dim dupeItems
Dim dupeList() As String

dQry = Me.cboUniqueName.Value
dupeItems = DLookup("Description", "Duplicates Table", "[Dupe Names] = '" & dQry & "'")
i = 0
For Each dupeItem In dupeItems
    ReDim Preserve dupeList(i)
    dupeList(i) = dupeItem
    i = i + 1
Next

Me.txtDescription.Value = dupeList
```

But this didn't work either.
Is there a known method of doing so? - I'm not very experienced with vba, so maybe I overlooked the answer to my problems.

I can try to rephrase my question if need be, but this is what I could think of.
Thank you!

Comment: Edit question to show sample data as text tables. You definitely misunderstand how DLookup() works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ms Access Query: Concatenating Rows through a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517233/ms-access-query-concatenating-rows-through-a-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my generic [DJoin](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.DJoin) function for this having a line feed as the separator:

```vb
Dim dQry As String
Dim dupeItems As String

dQry = Me.cboUniqueName.Value
dupeItems = DJoin("Description", "[Duplicates Table]", "[Dupe Names] = '" & dQry & "'", vbCrLf)
Me.txtDescription.Value = dupeItems
```

The function (complete module):

```vb
Option Explicit

' Returns the joined (concatenated) values from a field of records having the same key.
' The joined values are stored in a collection which speeds up browsing a query or form
' as all joined values will be retrieved once only from the table or query.
' Null values and zero-length strings are ignored.
'
' If no values are found, Null is returned.
'
' The default separator of the joined values is a space.
' Optionally, any other separator can be specified.
'
' Syntax is held close to that of the native domain functions, DLookup, DCount, etc.
'
' Typical usage in a select query using a table (or query) as source:
'
'   Select
'       KeyField,
'       DJoin("[ValueField]", "[Table]", "[KeyField] = " & [KeyField] & "") As Values
'   From
'       Table
'   Group By
'       KeyField
'
' The source can also be an SQL Select string:
'
'   Select
'       KeyField,
'       DJoin("[ValueField]", "Select ValueField From SomeTable Order By SomeField", "[KeyField] = " & [KeyField] & "") As Values
'   From
'       Table
'   Group By
'       KeyField
'
' To clear the collection (cache), call DJoin with no arguments:
'
'   DJoin
'
' Requires:
'   CollectValues
'
' 2019-06-11, Cactus Data ApS, Gustav Brock
'
Public Function DJoin( _
    Optional ByVal Expression As String, _
    Optional ByVal Domain As String, _
    Optional ByVal Criteria As String, _
    Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = " ") _
    As Variant
    
    ' Expected error codes to accept.
    Const CannotAddKey      As Long = 457
    Const CannotReadKey     As Long = 5
    ' SQL.
    Const SqlMask           As String = "Select {0} From {1} {2}"
    Const SqlLead           As String = "Select "
    Const SubMask           As String = "({0}) As T"
    Const FilterMask        As String = "Where {0}"
    
    Static Values   As New Collection
    
    Dim Records     As DAO.Recordset
    Dim SubRecords  As DAO.Recordset
    Dim Sql         As String
    Dim SqlSub      As String
    Dim Filter      As String
    Dim Value       As Variant
    Dim Result      As Variant
    
    On Error GoTo Err_DJoin
    
    If Expression = "" Then
        ' Erase the collection of keys.
        Set Values = Nothing
        Result = Null
    Else
        ' Get the values.
        ' This will fail if the current criteria hasn't been added
        ' leaving Result empty.
        Result = Values.Item(Criteria)
        '
        If IsEmpty(Result) Then
            ' The current criteria hasn't been added to the collection.
            ' Build SQL to lookup values.
            If InStr(1, LTrim(Domain), SqlLead, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                ' Domain is an SQL expression.
                SqlSub = Replace(SubMask, "{0}", Domain)
            Else
                ' Domain is a table or query name.
                SqlSub = Domain
            End If
            If Trim(Criteria) <> "" Then
                ' Build Where clause.
                Filter = Replace(FilterMask, "{0}", Criteria)
            End If
            ' Build final SQL.
            Sql = Replace(Replace(Replace(SqlMask, "{0}", Expression), "{1}", SqlSub), "{2}", Filter)
            
            ' Look up the values to join.
            Set Records = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Sql, dbOpenSnapshot)
            CollectValues Records, Delimiter, Result
            ' Add the key and its joined values to the collection.
            Values.Add Result, Criteria
        End If
    End If
    
    ' Return the joined values (or Null if none was found).
    DJoin = Result
    
Exit_DJoin:
    Exit Function
    
Err_DJoin:
    Select Case Err
        Case CannotAddKey
            ' Key is present, thus cannot be added again.
            Resume Next
        Case CannotReadKey
            ' Key is not present, thus cannot be read.
            Resume Next
        Case Else
            ' Some other error. Ignore.
            Resume Exit_DJoin
    End Select
    
End Function

' To be called from DJoin.
'
' Joins the content of the first field of a recordset to one string
' with a space as delimiter or an optional delimiter, returned by
' reference in parameter Result.
'
' 2019-06-11, Cactus Data ApS, Gustav Brock
'
Private Sub CollectValues( _
    ByRef Records As DAO.Recordset, _
    ByVal Delimiter As String, _
    ByRef Result As Variant)
    
    Dim SubRecords  As DAO.Recordset
    
    Dim Value       As Variant

    If Records.RecordCount > 0 Then
        While Not Records.EOF
            Value = Records.Fields(0).Value
            If Records.Fields(0).IsComplex Then
                ' Multi-value field (or attachment field).
                Set SubRecords = Records.Fields(0).Value
                CollectValues SubRecords, Delimiter, Result
            ElseIf Nz(Value) = "" Then
                ' Ignore Null values and zero-length strings.
            ElseIf IsEmpty(Result) Then
                ' First value found.
                Result = Value
            Else
                ' Join subsequent values.
                Result = Result & Delimiter & Value
            End If
            Records.MoveNext
        Wend
    Else
        ' No records found with the current criteria.
        Result = Null
    End If
    Records.Close

End Sub
```

Full documentation and demo can be found here:

[Join (concat) values from one field from a table or query](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33612/Join-concat-values-from-one-field-from-a-table-or-query.html)

Comment: My friend, you've done it. You've solved my question that I've been slamming my head for. Thank you!!!!!

Comment: I have a question about DJoin.
Would it be possible to format a time value in the output to "Short Time"?
I've tried

     DJoin("[strDescription] & '- out:' & Format([time1],'Short Time') ...

Still outputting a long time format. Thank you!!

Comment: `DJoin("[Description] & '- out:' & Format([time1],'Short Time')", "[Duplicates Table]", " ...` should work if `time1` is of data type _Date_.

Comment: aaa, thank you. I guess it was just outputting a cached result.

Comment: I've found that adding a `Expression = ""` after `End Select` in DJoin function, it fixes my "cached result"!

Comment: But that shortcuts the speed improvement. As stated: _To clear the collection (cache), call DJoin with no arguments._

Comment: Aaah, I see. Thank you again!