# combine 4 rows in to 1 all having unique values

Tags: ms-access, logic, ms-access-2010

[In this image you can see location is combination of different columns. The output i want needs to combine sizes S,M,L,XL to a single row and it should show only one location, Basically s,m,l,xl should be considered one. Also S is supposed to be on level 01,M on level 02, L on Level 03 & XL on 04)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEHxS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [DJoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62587753/combo-box-to-select-value-w-multiple-duplicates-populating-textbox-in-form-w/62589561#62589561) function for this, taken from my project [VBA.DJoin](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.DJoin).

This also includes a demo file, and you'll see an example on how to list sizes:

[image]

using a *multi-value* field:

[image]

However, you probably don't have that. Instead, you'll have to create a table with the sizes and a sorting order, for example:

[image]

and include that in the query you use as source with *DJoin*.