# Combining multiple records of data into one field

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

Given the following table:

```
ACCT_NUM    BEN_OPT_CD  BEN_PLN_TY  ACCUM_PROVSN_TY
0000025        CO1E     MHRD             2
0000025        CO1E     MHRD             3
0000025        CO1E     RXRD             1
0000025        CO1EF    MHRD             2
0000025        CO1EF    MHRD             3
0000025        CO1EF    RXRD             3
0000025        CO1EL    MHRD             1
0000025        CO1EL    MHRD             4
0000025        CO1EL    RXRD             3
0000025        CO1EN    MHRD             1
0000025        CO1EN    MHRD             2
0000025        CO1EN    MHRD             3
0000025        CO1EN    RXRD             3
```

How would I achieve these results in a query:

```
ACCT_NUM    BEN_OPT_CD  BEN_PLN_TY  ACCUM_PROVSN_TY
0000025        CO1E     MHRD             2, 3
0000025        CO1E     RXRD             1
0000025        CO1EF    MHRD             2, 3
0000025        CO1EF    MHRD             3
0000025        CO1EL    MHRD             1, 4
0000025        CO1EL    RXRD             3
0000025        CO1EN    MHRD             1, 2, 3
0000025        CO1EN    RXRD             3
```

Yes, I know it's not ideal.  Unfortunately I need to match up a report from another team and they display it in this format.  The table has less than 500K records, so it shouldn't be unwieldy.  There can be anywhere from 1 to 4 numbers in the final version of ACCUM_PROVSN_TY.

Comment: You can find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852892/is-there-a-group-concat-function-in-ms-access

Comment: Or my fast [DJoin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62589561/3527297) function.