# MS Access Query For Combining rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query which returns data in following format:

```
xxx yyy     count
-------------------------------
a   cat1    23
a   cat2    34
a   cat3    12
b   cat1    34
b   cat2    1
b   cat3    2
c   cat1    34
c   cat2    123
c   cat3    34
d   cat1    34
d   cat2    12
d   cat3    34
```

I need to modify my query in such a way that i need to categorize two values of yyy column into single and combine their count

```
xxx yyy         count
-------------------------------
a   cat1        23
a   cat2 & cat3 36
b   cat1        34
b   cat2 & cat3 3
c   cat1        34
c   cat2 & cat3 157
d   cat1        34
d   cat2 & cat3 36
```

Please suggest if you have any ideas!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92698/combine-rows-in-access-2007/93863#93863

Comment: Thanks for quick response Remou!!
i need to know if i can do this purely using sql statement.. ??

Comment: No, not in MS Access you can't.

Comment: I agree with Remou, although technically possible if the "cat" names do not change, you would end up "unioning" your SQL row by row and thus defeat the whole point of the exercise.

Comment: yes.. I agree.. Despite trying out all possible ways i could think of, i could acheive this..
I worked out a work around though.. Thanks all..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always want cat1 broken out and there are only 2 other cats...

```
SELECT xxx, yyy, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM table
WHERE yyy = 'cat1'
GROUP BY xxx, yyy
UNION
SELECT xxx, 'cat2 & cat3' AS yyy, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM table
WHERE yyy <> 'cat1'
GROUP BY xxx
```

If you there additional cats and you only want 2 and 3, change `WHERE yyy <> 'cat1'` to `WHERE yyy IN ('cat2','cat3')`