# Query to fetch data inline or comma separated data

Tags: sql, ms-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combine rows in Access 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92698/combine-rows-in-access-2007)

I have a table in MS Access Databse 
called as "emp_orders"

And the data appears as below,

```
emp_no  order_no 
1       123
1       156
1       264
2       234
2       354
2       268
2       182
```

now i need a select query which fetches data as specified below.

```
emp_no  orders
1       123,156,264
2       234,354,268,182
```

Please help me out to sort this.

Comment: So you want [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) in MS Access. All the best :)

Comment: You cannot do this without VBA, only available when you are working inside MS Access, that is, there is no pure sql answer for MS Access.