# Combine values from related rows into a single concatenated string value

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to aggregate some instructor data (to easily show which courses an instructor taught in a semester), and up until now I've just accepted having multiple rows for each instructor. However, it would be beneficial to some business processes if I could have all of an instructor's teaching in a single row. Here is some example data (my tables have a lot more columns, but the general idea won't change much.

tbl_Instructors has:

```
    N_ID | F_Name | L_Name
    001    Joe      Smith
    002    Henry    Fonda
    003    Lou      Reed
```

tbl_Courses has:

```
    Course_ID | N_ID | Course_Info
    AAA         001    PHYS 1
    AAB         001    PHYS 2
    CCC         002    PHYS 12
    DDD         003    PHYS 121
    FFF         003    PHYS 224
```

What I want to return is:

```
    N_ID | First_Name | Last_Name | Course_IDs
    001    Joe          Smith       AAA, AAB
    002    Henry        Fonda       CCC
    003    Lou          Reed        DDD, FFF
```

I think I need to do something with selecting all N_IDs from tbl_Instructors, then returning the Course_IDs from tbl_Courses via concatenation, but that magic step has alluded me. Any help? Can I do this via SQL selects or will I need to use VB?

Comment: Have you looked at crosstab queries? There is a wizard.

Comment: Alternatively : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92698/combine-rows-in-access-2007/93863#93863

Comment: @Remou I tried crosstab, but it wasn't ideal as it resulted in hundreds of columns (an individual column for each course). I'll read up more to see if I was just doing it wrong.

Comment: In that case, have a look at the link. It is about concatenating rows.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is easy using Allen Browne's [ConcatRelated()](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) function.  Copy the function from that web page and paste it into an Access standard code module.

Then this query will return what you asked for.

```
SELECT
    i.N_ID,
    i.F_Name,
    i.L_Name,
    ConcatRelated(
        "Course_ID",
        "tbl_Courses",
        "N_ID = '" & [N_ID] & "'"
        ) AS Course_IDs
FROM tbl_Instructors AS i;
```

Consider changing the data type of `N_ID` from text to numeric in both tables.  If you do that, you don't need the single quotes in the third argument to that `ConcatRelated()` expression.

```
"N_ID = " & [N_ID]
```

And whenever you need `N_ID` displayed with leading zeros, use a `Format()` expression.

```
Format(N_ID, "000")
```

Comment: THANK YOU! This worked perfectly with the test data I laid out (I wasn't able to figure out the info @Remou gave unfortunately). Now I'm going to integrate it into the real production data I have.

Comment: Any idea why I am running the code exactly as the answer is listed, and I get an error: "Ambiguous name in query expression ConcatRelated("field", "tbl", "ID = " & [ID]) I've spent quite a bit of time reading this article and others but no luck, my syntax and table structure is almost exactly like that listed above. Article: https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=179007

Comment: @TylerJones I wasn't around last summer when you left that comment.  I followed the link from your comment, but it doesn't help me understand your problem.  If you still need help with that, I suggest you post a new question.