# SQL to combine several rows into one

Tags: sql, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

I am writing a program which uses some data from an Access database.

I need a query for a result that will take (for example) 9 rows and combine it into a single row.

Here is a picture of the raw data.

[image]

Here is my query

```
SELECT 
    anime.animeID, anime.animeOriginaltitel, anime.animejapanesetitel, anime.animesolved, anime.animeLicensed, anime.animeproxerID, anime.animeseasonstart, 
    anime.animeseasonend, anime.animedescription, anime.animeEpisodes, anime_genrelist.genreName AS Genre
FROM
    ((anime INNER JOIN
      anime_anime_genre ON anime.animeID = anime_anime_genre.animeID) INNER JOIN
      anime_genrelist ON anime_anime_genre.genreID = anime_genrelist.genreID)
GROUP BY 
    anime.animeID, anime.animeOriginaltitel, anime.animejapanesetitel, anime.animesolved, anime.animeLicensed, anime.animeproxerID, anime.animeseasonstart, 
    anime.animeseasonend, anime.animedescription, anime.animeEpisodes, anime_genrelist.genreName
```

The last `anime_genrelist.genreName` at group by is inserted because there was an error.

Here is the result I need:

[image]

I use Visual Studio, NOT Access to become the result

Comment: What exactly is the problem? They are not grouped together as the genre is different (from what I'm seeing..)

Comment: Your question is not much clear, please elaborate a bit

Comment: i have add an picture of the needed result

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine values from related rows into a single concatenated string value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278590/combine-values-from-related-rows-into-a-single-concatenated-string-value)

Comment: sorry but when i use this solution i become the error Undefined function 'ConcatRelated' in expression

Comment: i use visual studio NOT access to become the query

Comment: @FlorianHofmeister the VBA function is located here http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

Comment: i know but i need an sql solution not with an modul from vb because i wrote in the visual studio query editor and there i can only use SQL

Comment: Pls  give me some Answere