# Create a concatenated list of child table values from an Access database without using VBA

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have an Access 2010 database with a relationship between parent and child tables. I would like to be able to query the database from an external application and show values from the child table as a concatenated list of values in a single column, similar to what MySQL can produce with its `GROUP_CONCAT()` function.

This has been asked here many times before, e.g., here:

[Combine values from related rows into a single concatenated string value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13278590/2144390)

but those solutions rely on a custom VBA function that is not available to external queries.

Is there a way to make such a concatenated list available to external queries without having to manually build the list in the other application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue

Historically, the Access solution for a `GROUP_CONCAT()`-type query has been to use a VBA function like Allen Browne's `ConcatRelated()` (ref: [here](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html)). However, custom VBA functions are only available to queries run from within Microsoft Access itself, so this is not a viable solution for queries against an Access database from some other application (e.g., a .NET application using OLEDB or ODBC).

### Solution

With an Access 2010 (or newer) database we can emulate the behaviour of a MySQL `GROUP_CONCAT()` query by adding a Long Text ("Memo") field to the parent table and using [data macros](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx) on the child table to maintain the concatenated list.

For example, for tables [Parents] ...

```
ParentID  ParentName   
--------  -------------
       1  Homer Simpson
       2  Ned Flanders
```

... and [Children] ...

```
ChildID  ParentID  ChildName          DisplayOrder
-------  --------  -----------------  ------------
      1         1  Lisa                          2
      2         1  Bart                          1
      3         2  Rod, the elder                1
      4         1  Maggie                        3
      5         2  Todd, the younger             2
```

... we can add a new `Memo`/`Long Text` field named [ChildList] to the [Parents] table and then add the following data macros to the [Children] table:

**[Named Macro: UpdateChildList]**

[image: UpdateChildList.png]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<DataMacros xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/accessservices/2009/11/application">
    <DataMacro Name="UpdateChildList">
        <Parameters>
            <Parameter Name="prmParentID"/>
        </Parameters>
        <Statements>
            <Action Collapsed="true" Name="SetLocalVar">
                <Argument Name="Name">newList</Argument>
                <Argument Name="Value">Null</Argument>
            </Action>
            <ForEachRecord>
                <Data Alias="c">
                    <Query>
                        <References>
                            <Reference Source="Children" Alias="c"/>
                        </References>
                        <Results>
                            <Property Source="c" Name="ChildName"/>
                        </Results>
                        <Ordering>
                            <Order Source="c" Name="DisplayOrder"/>
                        </Ordering>
                    </Query>
                    <WhereCondition>[c].[ParentID]=[prmParentID] And [c].[ChildName] Is Not Null</WhereCondition>
                </Data>
                <Statements>
                    <ConditionalBlock>
                        <If>
                            <Condition>Not IsNull([newList])</Condition>
                            <Statements>
                                <Action Collapsed="true" Name="SetLocalVar">
                                    <Argument Name="Name">newList</Argument>
                                    <Argument Name="Value">[newList] &amp; ";" &amp; Chr(160)</Argument>
                                </Action>
                            </Statements>
                        </If>
                    </ConditionalBlock>
                    <Action Collapsed="true" Name="SetLocalVar">
                        <Argument Name="Name">newList</Argument>
                        <Argument Name="Value">[newList] &amp; [c].[ChildName]</Argument>
                    </Action>
                </Statements>
            </ForEachRecord>
            <LookUpRecord>
                <Data>
                    <Reference>Parents</Reference>
                    <WhereCondition>[Parents].[ParentID]=[prmParentID]</WhereCondition>
                </Data>
                <Statements>
                    <EditRecord>
                        <Data/>
                        <Statements>
                            <Action Collapsed="true" Name="SetField">
                                <Argument Name="Field">Parents.ChildList</Argument>
                                <Argument Name="Value">[newList]</Argument>
                            </Action>
                        </Statements>
                    </EditRecord>
                </Statements>
            </LookUpRecord>
        </Statements>
    </DataMacro>
</DataMacros>
```

**[After Insert]**

[image: AfterInsert.png]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<DataMacros xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/accessservices/2009/11/application">
    <DataMacro Event="AfterInsert">
        <Statements>
            <Action Name="RunDataMacro">
                <Argument Name="MacroName">Children.UpdateChildList</Argument>
                <Parameters>
                    <Parameter Name="prmParentID" Value="[ParentID]"/>
                </Parameters>
            </Action>
        </Statements>
    </DataMacro>
</DataMacros>
```

**[After Update]**

[image: AfterUpdate.png]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<DataMacros xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/accessservices/2009/11/application">
    <DataMacro Event="AfterUpdate">
        <Statements>
            <ConditionalBlock>
                <If>
                    <Condition>Updated("ParentID") Or Updated("ChildName")</Condition>
                    <Statements>
                        <Action Name="RunDataMacro">
                            <Argument Name="MacroName">Children.UpdateChildList</Argument>
                            <Parameters>
                                <Parameter Name="prmParentID" Value="[ParentID]"/>
                            </Parameters>
                        </Action>
                        <ConditionalBlock>
                            <If>
                                <Condition>Updated("ParentID")</Condition>
                                <Statements>
                                    <Action Name="RunDataMacro">
                                        <Argument Name="MacroName">Children.UpdateChildList</Argument>
                                        <Parameters>
                                            <Parameter Name="prmParentID" Value="[Old].[ParentID]"/>
                                        </Parameters>
                                    </Action>
                                </Statements>
                            </If>
                        </ConditionalBlock>
                    </Statements>
                </If>
            </ConditionalBlock>
        </Statements>
    </DataMacro>
</DataMacros>
```

**[After Delete]**

[image: AfterDelete.png]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<DataMacros xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/accessservices/2009/11/application">
    <DataMacro Event="AfterDelete">
        <Statements>
            <Action Name="RunDataMacro">
                <Argument Name="MacroName">Children.UpdateChildList</Argument>
                <Parameters>
                    <Parameter Name="prmParentID" Value="[Old].[ParentID]"/>
                </Parameters>
            </Action>
        </Statements>
    </DataMacro>
</DataMacros>
```

### Results

As changes are made to the child table the list in the parent table will automatically be updated:

```
ParentID  ParentName     ChildList                        
--------  -------------  ---------------------------------
       1  Homer Simpson  Bart; Lisa; Maggie               
       2  Ned Flanders   Rod, the elder; Todd, the younger
```

### Notes

1. The [ChildList] field is for display purposes only. Editing the values in that field will *not* change the values in the child table.
2. The list is separated with `";" & Chr(160)` to differentiate it from any `";" & Chr(32)` pairs that may be in the actual data. If the non-breaking space (`Chr(160)`) characters mess up wrapping of the list then we could use the `Replace()` function in our query to convert `";" & Chr(160)` to `";" & Chr(32)` or `"," & Chr(32)` or whatever would be most appropriate.
3. To populate the lists with existing child data we simply need to "update" one child record for each parent, like so

```
UPDATE Children SET ChildName=ChildName 
WHERE ChildID IN (SELECT MIN(ChildID) AS m FROM Children GROUP BY ParentID)
```

Comment: Another benefit of your suggestion is less effort for Access to retrieve the concatenated values (compared to a VBA function).