# MS Access Query - One-to-Many Concatenation

Tags: ms-access

I am looking for general guidance here, please.

I have a query that joins to datasets.  One of the attributes legitimately provides MANY results.  I don't need MANY row for my purposes.  Rather, I'd like to concatenate the MANY results into a single attribute:

CatResult:  "Value1, Value2, Value3..."

Question:  Any suggested approach to accomplish this task via query?  I suppose I could construct a VBA approach to step thru the recordset and concatenate as needed.  More curious to learn if there is a query-based approach to try.

Any suggestions to get me past step one?

Comment: Also see: [Create a concatenated list of child table values from an Access database without using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076586/create-a-concatenated-list-of-child-table-values-from-an-access-database-without/30076587)

Comment: To answer the second question, there is no pure SQL solution in Access. You need the VBA function. Note that performance won't be great if the input query has a large result set.