# Getting Select Query Result in a single row MS Access 2010

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2010

I am trying to get select query result in a single row, but its giving me a syntax error
Here is the query

```
SELECT csv.ControlKey+'|' +csv.ControlName+'|'+fs.SheetName+'||' AS Result
From CSVData as csv
Inner Join FilesSheets as fs
ON csv.FileId=fs.FileId
AND csv.SheetNo=fs.SheetNo
Where csv.FileId='(20101010)20Y-27-22170_4Ä¦_20151215101623.xls'
For xml path('')
```

Here is the syntax error
[image]

But if I remove `For xml path('')` from query it works fine but return multiple rows

Comment: becoz `For xml path('')` belongs to `Sql Server` not `Ms-Access`

Comment: Check here http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html to do this in Ms-Access

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine values from related rows into a single concatenated string value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278590/combine-values-from-related-rows-into-a-single-concatenated-string-value)