# Concatenate multiple rows in one field in Access ( loop to avoid 255 character/field limit.)

Tags: sql, ms-access, concatenation

formula working but have limitation 255 characters in field , i need add next column for every 255 characters.... if result: TV/Phone/Internet <255 im looking for some kind of loop back and create next column with additional (missing) results for this Query, like i mentioned before function working perfectly but i'm loosing data  there

### Current table:

```
Order Number | Product Types

100001 | TV
100001 | Phone
100001 | Internet
100002 | Phone
100003 | TV
100003 | Internet
```

### Desired reference table

```
100001 | TV/Phone/Internet
100002 | Phone
100003 | TV/Internet
```

solution working:

Allen Browne provides a function which you may find useful for this: Concatenate values from related records. Save that function's code in a standard module.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [Order Number],
    ConcatRelated("[Product Types]",
        "YourTable",
        "[Order Number] = " & [Order Number],
        "[Product Types]",
        "/"
        ) AS All_Product_Types
FROM YourTable;
```

---

but "Product Types" have 255 characters limitation
Im asking if someone can help for example show me how to put result to memo field , or help me create loop for every 255 CHar , then for next 255 place result to "Product types 2" etc.... ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine values from related rows into a single concatenated string value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278590/combine-values-from-related-rows-into-a-single-concatenated-string-value)

Comment: yes  but "[Product Types]" in access field can have only 255 characters ,  my database much bigger and i need solve (bypass) this limit somehow, fo example create "[Product Types2 ]" for additional result, or put "[Product Types]" to memofield (no limit there~) ,,, other wise function working perfectly- thats what im trying to explain