# Combine rows / concatenate rows in one field on report

Tags: ms-access

Hi I would like to know how to get the following in Access 2010

I would like to run a date query to select data in the column and then would like to put all the relevant data in the column on one field in a report.

Example of column: from date query.

```
this is blue
this is black
this is yellow
```

output on report

```
this is black this is blue this is yellow.
```

How do I do this?

Comment: It seems that you want to do this inside the Access interface, if so then you need to add the VBA tag and remove the VB.NET one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine values from related rows into a single concatenated string value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278590/combine-values-from-related-rows-into-a-single-concatenated-string-value)

Comment: Look into using a SQL query for your report then you can use CONCAT which is a SQL command that will combine multiple rows into one.

Comment: CONCAT is a SQL Server function and will not work in Access. Furthermore, it concatenates values, NOT rows.

Comment: Hi thanks for the responses but I don't know VB

Comment: Maybe [Concatenate values from related records](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) will help? I know you don't use VBA, neither do I, but this link will guide you how to use this function.

Comment: I have tried but cant get this to work