# SQL (Access) returning multiple records as one row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ms-access-2010, excel-2010

```
ClaimNo, Diag1, Diag2, Diag3, Diag4, CPT Code
   1     v912                        97729
   1     v912   762.3                81029
   1     v912   762.3  333.9         15321 
   1     v912   762.3  333.9  213.0  71100
```

Is it possible to write a query that returns the above information as one row?  For example:

```
ClaimNo, Diag1, Diag2, Diag3, Diag4, CPT Codes
   1     v912   762.3  333.9  213.0  97729, 81029, 15321, 71100
```

This may be little simpler, but what about code that just captures the different CPT codes as one record:

```
ClaimNo, CPT Codes
   1     97729, 81029, 15321, 71100
```

For this purpose I was hoping to see Microsoft Access syntax against Microsoft SQL Server 2012. I would be dealing with many records and much larger claim numbers. A Claim could have more or less CPT codes than the example listed.

Is it also possible to do something like this with Excel using embedded INDEX and MATCH function?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Access?  There are a ton of questions about doing CSV aggregation in SQL Server, have you tried any of them?

Comment: I would mostly be using Access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine values from related rows into a single concatenated string value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278590/combine-values-from-related-rows-into-a-single-concatenated-string-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BEGIN TRAN
CREATE TABLE #Temp(ClaimNo VARCHAR(100),Diag1 VARCHAR(100),Diag2 VARCHAR(100),Diag3 VARCHAR(100),Diag4 VARCHAR(100),CPTCode VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #Temp(ClaimNo ,Diag1,Diag2,Diag3,Diag4,CPTCode)
SELECT '1','v912','','','','97729' UNION ALL
SELECT '1','v912','762.3','','','81029' UNION ALL
SELECT '1','v912','762.3','333.9','','15321' UNION ALL
SELECT '1','v912','762.3','333.9','213.0','71100' 

SELECT ClaimNo , STUFF((SELECT ',' + CPTCode FROM #Temp FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
FROM #Temp
GROUP BY ClaimNo


ROLLBACK TRAN
```