# Make a query that show result in another column

Tags: sql, vb6

i have a table like this :

```
id - name - referred_id - referred_name
1  - mark -   100  -      nick
2  - david-   100  -      nick 
3  - mat -    100  -      nick
4  - patrik-  101  -      robert
5  - mick -   101  -      robert
```

i use this query to show result for referred name:

```
SELECT member_id,f_name,l_name,active_status,refered_by From Act_Reg where refered_by='nick'
```

query works good and return:

```
id - name
1  - mark
2  - david
3  - mat
```

now, i want to show results in a grid as row and coloumn :like this

```
id - referred_id - referred_name - refers(name of refers)
1  -  100        - nick          - mark , david , mat
2  -  101        - robert        - patrik , mick
```

My goal is that anyone who has introduced as report,for example:
nick introduced mark,david,mat
I use a access as database, thanks all

Comment: Which RDBMS? `SQL-Server`, `MySQL` or else?

Comment: You have some answers based on your sample data. I wonder if nick and robert also are in the table with their own Id? Ie. the referredId is an id of someone else in the same table? You may have alternative answers if this is the case

Comment: i use access 2003

Comment: there is one table with this fields: id - name - referred_id - referred_name

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server stance. (There is possibly a more efficient way, but a way just the same)

```
SELECT  distinct
        referred_id,
        referred_name,

        STUFF((SELECT ', ' + data1.[name] 
        FROM tablename data1
        WHERE data1.referred_id = data.referred_id
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [refers (name of refers)]


FROM    tablename data
```

rename your tables and aliases where applicable. Your id column in your example doesn't fit with your desired results.

courtesy of

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2914/rolling-up-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-column-for-sql-server-data/

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not mentioning about which RDBMS, I'm providing solution for the SQL-Server:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Id, 
       referred_id, 
       referred_name, 
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(name AS VARCHAR(10)) [n]
         FROM TestTable 
         WHERE referred_id = t.referred_id
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') name
FROM TestTable t
GROUP BY referred_id, referred_name;
```

Output:

```
Id  referred_id     referred_name   name
1   100             nick            mark, david, mat
2   101             robert          patrik, mick
```

Working Demo: http://rextester.com/ICC58106

**Update:**

In case if you want to get the results to the specific referred_user then you need to add the `WHERE` clause before the `GROUP BY`:

```
WHERE referred_name = 'nick'
```

Comment: Sorry, can you write query to compatable with access ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    referred_id
    ,referred_name
    ,(
        SELECT SUBSTRING((
            SELECT 
                ', ' + NAME
            FROM Act_Reg 
            WHERE REFERRED_ID = A.REFERRED_ID        
            FOR XML PATH('')),
        3,1000)
    ) [REFERS [NAME OF REFERES]
FROM Act_Reg A
-- INSERT WHERE CLAUSE HERE, IF NEEDED
GROUP BY referred_id, referred_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Access answer. Thanks to [Combine values from related rows into a single concatenated string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278590/combine-values-from-related-rows-into-a-single-concatenated-string-value)

SQL:

```
SELECT distinct
i.[referred_name],
ConcatRelated(
    "[name]",
    "names",
"[referred_name] = '" & [referred_name] & "'") AS Names
FROM [names] AS i;
```

create a module and paste in ConcatRelated Method which is mentioned in the link provided. http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

I've tested on access 2002-2003 and works.

Comment: Thanks Rob White, But i use access 2003 as database and use vb6.vb6 does not recognized  "ConcatRelated",what should i do ? is there way to reach my goal with another query ?

Comment: Everything I've looked into would suggest a query is not an option, but it's not like I've read every single page online so who knows. I would suggest pulling the data as it is and then use vb to build your desired results. Depending on the size of the data it might be slow and unworkable but that's for your discretion.