# Combining different values into one cell but also having totals

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to manage our inventory on access but I'm very new to it. My raw data lists out items, quantity requested, and the crews that requested it. I want to see the sum of the quantity requested for an item and the associated crews but I want all the crews to be in one cell. I've tried searching up the question and people suggest using the concatenate function but I don't know how to change it for my situation as I want the totals as well (and I don't know anything about SQL or VBA). Any help would be appreciated!
This is how my data looks

```
||ID||  ||ITEM||    ||Qty requested||   ||Crew||
||1||   ||bolt||    ||2||               ||1234||
||1||   ||bolt||    ||30||              ||4567||
||2||   ||saw||     ||4||               ||7890||
||3||   ||screw||   ||10||              ||1234||
||4||   ||glove||   ||1||               ||1111||
||4||   ||glove||   ||5||               ||222||
```

but I want it to look like this

```
||ID||  ||ITEM||    ||Qty requested||   ||Crew||
||1||   ||bolt||    ||32||              ||1234,4567||
||2||   ||saw||     ||4||               ||7890||
||3||   ||screw||   ||10||              ||1234||
||4||   ||glove||   ||6||               ||1111,222||
```

I've tried running a query but the closest I can get is a table with the items and sum of the quantities but not the crews. Thank you!

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278590/combine-values-from-related-rows-into-a-single-concatenated-string-value

Comment: I tried doing that but what I have sums up the all of the quantities and lists all the Crews, I have this SELECT 
Sum(Qty_Requested) AS Total_Qty_Requested
     , ConcatRelated("Crew", "Table") AS Crew
FROM Table t;

Comment: Did you download the function and add it?

Comment: Yeah I did, I think I didn't specify in my query that it should repeat based on Item name (like recursion?) but I don't know how to do that

Comment: Should edit your question to show the attempted query SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Your table is named Table?

Consider:

`SELECT ID, Item, Sum(Qty_Requested) AS Total_Qty_Requested, ConcatRelated("Crew", "Table", "ID=" & [ID]) AS Crews FROM Table GROUP BY ID, Item;`