# Combining Excel Tables using Excel or Access 2003

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, ms-access-2003, excel-2003

I am trying to create a merged dataset using Excel or Access and am not having much luck. I have two Excel tables, both contain ID's that I can link them with. However, TABLE1 has only one row for each ID, TABLE2 can contain multiple rows for each ID. I want to keep all entries in TABLE1 and add in the values from TABLE2, separating multiples by a comma. Example:

```
 **TABLE1**
    CNid    start   stop
    0001    1        50
    0002    60      100
    0003    1        20

 **TABLE2**
    CNid    gene
    0001    abc
    0001    ijk
    0001    qrs
    0003    abc

 **TABLE3(Created)**
    CNid    start   stop    gene
    0001    1        50      abc,ijk,qrs
    0002    60      100 
    0003    1        20      abc
```

I am familiar with merge query in Access, but cannot figure out how to make the resulting table only have one row for each CNid.

Comment: If a crosstab does not suit, you can use VBA -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92698/combine-rows-in-access-2007/93863#93863

Answer (score 0):

Although I use Excel 2007 I think this will work in Excel 2003 but I'll separate out the steps just in case:

1. Create a PivotTable from Table2 with `CNid` for Row Labels, `gene` for Column Labels and Count of gene for Σ  Values.
2. With layout as example, in L8 put:

   > =IF(F8=1,F$7,"")

and copy across to suit, then copy down L8 to wherever.

[image: SO13362680 example]

3. In I8 put:

   > =L8&","&M8&","&N8&","&O8&","&P8

Extend as necessary and copy down to suit.

4. Copy ColumnI and Paste Special Values into ColumnJ.
5. Select ColumnJ and replace `,,` with nothing.
6. In K8 put:

   > =IF(RIGHT(J8,1)=",",LEFT(J8)-1,J8)

and copy down to suit.

7. Add `gene` label to Table1, say this is in D12.
8. Name ColumnsE:K `geneArray` with Workbook scope.
9. In D13 put:

   > =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A13,geneArray,7,0)),"",VLOOKUP(A13,geneArray,7,0))

and copy down to suit.

10. Copy ColumnD and Paste Special Values over the top.
11. Delete what is no longer required.