# Comparing and contrasting concatenating fields in access?

Tags: ms-access

This is a great site, and I thank everyone for the questions and comments. I am working with a few dozens columns of data within an access database. Depending on this data, certain combinations of records can be combined. I need to track these and also update if certain fields change. Out of all the data provided, I really only need to look at 3 columns. For example,

```
Client    Group       Document
111       4444        A
111       5555        A
111       6666        B
111       7777        C
222       8888        A
222       9999        C
```

I used [ConcatRelated() in Access, using two keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822588/concatrelated-in-access-using-two-keys) to help me doing the concatenating part. I was able to turn it into this...

```
Client     Group              Document
111        4444,5555          A
111        6666               B
111        7777               C
222        8888               A
222        9999               C
```

Here is the puzzle. The data in Group and Document can always be changing, and I need to find a way to track if a record changes or stays the same. So in the above example, say client 111, group 4444 now needs document D instead of A, what would be the best practice to find that difference?

```
    Client     Group              Document
    111        5555               A
    111        6666               B
    111        7777               C
    111        4444               D
```

Should I even worry about the concatenating part and find a better way of reporting ... pivot tables, forms, etc? I have been thinking about this too long and am getting lost. Thanks again.

Comment: My gut reaction is you should track track changes at the source record level instead of after record concatenation.  Allen Browne also provides [Creating an Audit Log](http://allenbrowne.com/appaudit.html).  Perhaps you can adapt his approach for your change tracking.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will take a look at that. At first I thought doing the concatenate module would be enough, but this data is changing more than I anticipated.