# Microsoft Access - Using Concat related on a field with a compound key

Tags: sql, ms-access, concatenation, compound-key

I am working on trying to use Allen Browns ConcatRelated() method (http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) on a table in the following format:

```
[id1 | id2 | id3 | id4 | id5 | otherfield | year]
```

where id1 to id5 are the fields I need matching to concatenate years on.

For example:

```
1|2|3|4|5|abc|2017
1|2|3|4|5|abc|2018
```

should become

```
1|2|3|4|5|abc|2017,2018
```

I have used Concatrelated in the past but I am unsure of what to do when the key is made up multiple attributes.

Thanks, and sorry if my description is unclear

Comment: This may answer your question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822588/concatrelated-in-access-using-two-keys.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for!