Group two fields and combine items in a third field using a comma separator
I want to group two fields and combine items in a third field using a comma separator
I am using MS Access DB and the data in the tables is as follows
line                 spool         joint
10-CWR-1001-1P1(A)     A             1 
10-CWR-1001-1P1(A)     A             2
10-CWR-1001-1P1(A)     A             7
10-CWR-1001-1P1(A)     B             4
10-CWR-1001-1P1(A)     B             6

The expected output that I am looking
line                 spool         joint
10-CWR-1001-1P1(A)     A            1,2,7
10-CWR-1001-1P1(A)     B             4,6

I have a MS Access database and no other DB. I am requesting your help with this issue. Thank you

In Access, this must be done with VBA. Common topic "concatenate related records". Here is one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822588/concatrelated-in-access-using-two-keys. Now when you have code with specific issue, post question.

Are you actually repeatedly saving Line descriptive text instead of a foreign key ID?
