# Microsoft Access: returning results from multiple rows in one row based on a grouping variable (a field in the table)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working on fish growth rates so I need to pull weight and date for each time a single fish was measured.

Right now each capture record is on a separate line. I basically want to pull `pitcode`, `species`, `tagdate1`, `length1`, `weight1`, `tagdate2`, `length2`, `weight2`, `tagdate3`, etc.. from this table, grouped by `pitcode` and sorted by `tagdate`. I'm using Microsoft Access. Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

```
pitcode         tagdate       length  weight    species
3D9.1C2D9C7FCE  7/26/2011   213 118 3
3D9.1C2D9F3AB2  7/26/2011   148 38  3
3D9.1C2D9F1627  7/26/2011   215 116 3
3D9.1C2D60CDC6  7/26/2011   165 58  3
3D9.1C2D9F0797  7/26/2011   244 204 3
3D9.1C2D9BA47F  7/26/2011   143 47  3
3D9.1C2D9FD674  7/27/2011   226 183 3
3D9.1C2DA1C597  7/27/2011   123 27.2    3
3D9.1C2D9FE09F  7/27/2011   241 182.3   3
3D9.1C2D9FE4D8  7/27/2011   286 301 3
```

I found this "self join" from another post, and it works:

```
SELECT
  a.pitcode, 
  MIN(a.tagdate) AS td1, MIN(b.tagdate) AS td2, 
  MIN(a.weight) AS wt1, MIN(b.weight) AS wt2
FROM
  tagd a
  LEFT JOIN tagd b
  ON a.pitcode = b.pitcode AND b.tagdate > a.tagdate and b.weight>a.weight
GROUP BY
  a.pitcode;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine rows in Access 2007](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92698/combine-rows-in-access-2007) This is just one example with the same problem there are at least three others.

Comment: I guess I'm wondering if it's possible entirely with sql. I'm not familiar with VB, which I think this is using. Maybe something similar to the lag function in SAS?

Comment: No it is not possible to group records in MS Access on to one line with SQL.

Comment: okay. thank you. I'll have to try something else then. I appreciate the response.

Comment: I found this from another post, and it works:

Comment: It works for a predefined number of rows, not a variable number of rows. In the example you show for 2 rows, but in your question you refer to at least 3 rows.

Comment: yakamafish, you should put your solution down below and answer your own question so people know it has been solved.