# Merge partially duplicate rows into one row in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a select query, it gives out rows that are partially duplicate, I want to the duplicate rows to be merged into one row with the non duplicate values to be comma separated. 
Current output of the query is:

```
    **Contacts           Department                    Type**    
    Elena Stone          Biology                       Impact
    Elena Stone          Biochemistry                  Impact
    Elena Stone          Biotechnology                 Other
```

My desired output should be:

```
    **Contacts           Department                                 Type**   
     Elena Stone          Biology,Biochemistry,Biotechnology        Impact,other
```

Can some one please help me how to get this.
Thank You

Comment: What have you tried already?  You should be able to use some VBA to make a new table and concatenate the `Department` and `Type` if the `Contacts` already exist, else make add a new record.  I'm sure there is also SQL to do this but I'm not great with SQL.

Comment: Is there a way add this condition in the select query itself, if not how do I go about writing the VBA? I am actually using this query to gather data from tow tables to generate a report.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not very good with the queries or SQL...  But I've added an answer below that works for me.  It just doesn't check for duplicates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine rows / concatenate rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92698/combine-rows-concatenate-rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get to VBA you press ALT+F11 and that will bring up the editor.  Since you're not developing a form, you can just create a module.  Go to Insert, and select Module and you'll see a blank window with `Option Compare Database` across the top.

To start your module you create a sub function and put you're code there:

```
Public Sub CleverNameHere()

    'Code

End Sub
```

When you save this, do not name the module the same name as `CleverNameHere`, because if you ever have to call it then it will look like this `ModuleNameHere.CleverNameHere` and the parenthesis are for parameters.

From there you will just write something that calls your table, creates a recordset, and takes a record line by line and manipulates it until end of file (EOF).  Maybe something like this:

```
Public Sub CompareDuplicates()

Dim myR As Recordset
Dim myR2 As Recordset

Set myR = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Original_Table", dbOpenDynaset)
Set myR2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Duplicate_Table", dbOpenDynaset)

Do Until myR.EOF = True
    myR2.FindFirst ("Contacts = '" & myR![Contacts] & "'")
    If myR2.NoMatch = True Then
        myR2.AddNew
        myR2![Contacts] = myR![Contacts]
        myR2![Department] = myR![Department]
        myR2![Type] = myR![Type]
        myR2.Update
    Else
        myR2.Edit
        myR2![Department] = myR2![Department] & ", " & myR![Department]
        myR2![Type] = myR2![Type] & ", " & myR![Type]
        myR2.Update
    End If
    myR.MoveNext

Loop

Set myR = Nothing

End Sub
```