# Access Query - Removing Duplicate Results

Tags: ms-access

I have created an MS Access Database. I succesfully run a query on the database - but I want to compress duplicate fields:

Currently I get the results:

```
Page One | Link One | Function One
Page One | Link One | Function Two
Page One | Link One | Function Three
```

All I want the query to return is:

```
Page One | Link One | Function One Function Two Function Three
```

I believe that two sub-querys are required to concatenate the Link and Function columns. If so, how can I link these two sub-querys to my main query?

Comment: In an effort to help myself I have found the following article: http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html.

Comment: Oddly enough, it is easier with ADO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92698/combine-rows-concatenate-rows/93863#93863

Comment: +1 for Allen Browne's code. It works really well. ;)

Comment: Yep, another +1 for Allen Browne. The concat function is cool.