# MS ACCESS Combine Multiple Rows of data based on column

Tags: ms-access, concatenation

I have a database with a table with the following 3 columns of data:

> ```
> WORKORDER  -  SEQNBR  -  COMMENT
> R12345           1       This work was performed on Dec 3
> R12345           2       1999 and resulted in the removal
> R12345           3       or all similar pumps. All pumps 
> R12345           4       have been replace or repair
> ```

I'm looking to combine or concatnate  all of the COMMENTS for a particular WORKORDER into one column or report text box

Ex: R12345 "This work was performed on Dec 3 1999 and resulted in the removal or all similar pumps. All pumps have been replace or repair.

Is this possible?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Please read [ask]. Then add some sql to show us what you've tried and how it failed.

Comment: There are a number of answers on SO, here is one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92698/combine-rows-concatenate-rows/93863#93863. They all have problems in that they do not work outside of MS Access.

Comment: SEQNBR is always 1 to 4 or it may change ?

Answer (score 0):

MS-Access (and SQL Server) are a pain when it comes to concatenate data of a group. As said by others, there is no good solution for this problem in MS-Access.

Here is however something that will give you what you expect on your example. It assumes that you have a limited number of elements in your sequence (here, I supposed 4). It's ugly, but sometimes, it's necessary to be humble.

```
SELECT t1.WORKORDER & " " & t1.COMMENT & " " & t2.COMMENT & " " & t3.COMMENT & " " & t4.COMMENT AS Result
FROM ((your_table AS t1 LEFT JOIN your_table AS t2 ON t1.WORKORDER = t2.WORKORDER) 
LEFT JOIN your_table AS t3 ON t2.WORKORDER = t3.WORKORDER) 
LEFT JOIN your_table AS t4 ON t3.WORKORDER = t4.WORKORDER
WHERE t1.SEQNBR=1 
AND t2.SEQNBR=2 
AND t3.SEQNBR=3 
AND t4.SEQNBR=4
```

From this you get one record with one field containing:

> R12345 This work was performed on Dec 3 1999 and resulted in the
>   removal or all similar pumps. All pumps  have been replace or repair