# Special Join on two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have these tables in MS Access :

[image: Tables Schema]

I need a special join query to give me result like following:

list of all words in table 'pat_Words' that have synonyms in table 'pat_Synonyms'

```
Keen         eager,enthusiast,avid

Shelter      refuge,sanctuary
```

Comment: You need VBA t make this work in MS Access, unfortunately, VBA only works in an Access environment check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92698/combine-rows-concatenate-rows/93863#93863

Comment: @Fionnuala wow,Thanks that's so useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `mysql` you can do this

```
select word, group_concat(synonym) from pat_Words join pat_synonyms on pat_Words.word_id = pat_synonyms.word_id group by pat_Words.word_id
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Thanks,I like your answer but what about MS access?

Comment: Maybe add an MS Access tag to the question - it's helpful to let people know what DBMS you are using when asking questions like this.

Comment: Try this: http://www.rogersaccesslibrary.com/forum/generic-function-to-concatenate-child-records_topic16&SID=453fabc6-b3z9-34z6zb14-a78f832z-19z89a2c.html. I have no idea whether it works.