# Logically group Microsoft Access Report headers

Tags: vba, ms-access, report

I have a MS Access Query which I would like to create a report from (preferably using the wizard).

I want to know if there is a way to logically group several of the headers together so that when the report is printed, I would have customized the groups by using the criteria.

For example, let's say that I have a field "Name".
When the report is generated, I want the first header to read Brad, Bailey and Charlie and under that, would be only the records which include those names.
Then the next header will group the records together by the names
Frank, Eric and Mark

Comment: You could concatenate ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/93863/2548 ) but that might be slow and fail outside Access or you could rethink your design so that family name becomes a main heading and given name is listed under that.

Comment: I think I need to clarify...

Inisde my query, in my criteria I have "Brad Or Bailey Or Charlie" in one field. 

When the report is produced, I want the report broken into sections:
Brad Bailey Charlie
(Followed by statistics)

Should be the first section

Answer (score 0):

In your report you could:

1. Change the recordsource to include the query, but an additional field.  e.g. Display:"Brad Bailey Charlie"
2. Then in your report, group by Display with a header.  Add 'Display' field to the header.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table object with two fields: displayGroup and displayName. Enter "Brad Bailey Charlie" as a displayGroup value three times, with each of these records having one of Brad, Bailey, and Charlie in the displayName field. Then, build a query that joints your existing table to this table on the condition that your table's name field equals the displayName field. This will give you a grouping of the records you need for your report, with a field value to pass as the title.