# SQL Aggregate (concat) text based on another text field value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am looking for a sql statement that aggregates (concatenates) a text value based on another text value. I’m working in ms access. Here is an example of the table source.

```
ChangeNumber     Approver
123              Hey
123              You
```

I’ve tried group by statements which worked if I wanted to return a count. 
Example

```
select changenumber, count(approver)
From Changeapprover
Group by changenumber
```

However I cannot sum this field because it is text.

Result should be

```
ChangeNumber     Approver
123              Hey, You
```

This information exists originally in the same table. Column 1 contains duplicates. The resulting column 2 should concat the values of the original column 2 if the value for column 1 is identical.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine values from related rows into a single concatenated string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278590/combine-values-from-related-rows-into-a-single-concatenated-string-value)

Comment: Using Access, I would most likely try to write a function to do this for me. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92698/combine-rows-concatenate-rows